# Fetchxml with ( condition 1 or conditon 2) and condition 3

Tags: fetchxml

I need to create a view in MS Dynamics CRM 2015 that adds a couple of AND conditions to a series of OR conditions. The following doesn't work and nothing else seems to be allowed.

```
   <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" >
  <entity name="new_crn" >
    <attribute name="new_name" />
    <filter type="or" >
      <condition value="14" operator="eq" attribute="new_totalprod" />
      <condition value="14" operator="lt" attribute="new_totalprod" />
      <condition operator="between" attribute="new_totalprod" >
        <value>53</value>
        <value>93</value>
      </condition>
        ...  
    <filter type="and">
      <condition operator="eq" attribute="date_sent" >
    </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to revise the fetchxml by embedding both filters within another filter.  This did what I needed it to do.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" >
  <entity name="new_crn" >
    <attribute name="new_name" />
   <filter type="and">
     <filter type="or" >
        <condition value="14" operator="eq" attribute="new_totalprod" />
        <condition value="14" operator="lt" attribute="new_totalprod" />
        <condition operator="between" attribute="new_totalprod" >
          <value>53</value>
          <value>93</value>
        </condition>
        ...  
        <filter type="and">
         <condition operator="eq" attribute="date_sent" >
        </filter>
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```